# How to make accordion with table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/QtNbC/48/), but it doesn't work properly. I want to hide it when I have a lot of main lines and sublines. Thanks for your help. (Click on first line, where is "1"). I made a video to make it clear -

http://youtu.be/FuIC-t4WKQ8

My code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("#report tr:first-child").show();

    $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings("tr").toggle();
        $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
    });

    //$("#report").jExpand();
});
```

Comment: can we have some html? possibly a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QtNbC/48/

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have `<div>` tags in your `<table>` and you cannot have multiple elements with the same `id`. You can accomplish the same thing by combining these tables into a single table, and instead of using DIVs as handles use the TRs directly:

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".handle").click(function(){
        $(this)
            .toggleClass('open')
                .nextUntil(".handle")
                    .children()
                    .slideToggle('fast');
    });

});
```

CSS

```
table#report {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
table#report tbody tr:not(.handle) td{
    display:none
}
table#report tbody tr.handle td:first-child:before {
    content: '>';
    color:gray;
    float:left;
    transition:all 1s;
}
table#report tbody tr.handle.open td:first-child:before {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    color:red;
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9gcFJ/

Comment: How can I edit color of my row. Here is a picture of my table - http://i.imgur.com/s3p4EmA.jpg

At the left side I have not open table row, at the right side I have open table. Colors of my talbe change by this code http://jsfiddle.net/ff8Gn/ I want to make colors like in right side but when my table is not open. Here is CSS of my table http://jsfiddle.net/ff8Gn/1/

Comment: Add this javascript (using css will count non-handle rows): `$(".handle:odd").addClass("odd");` And add a css for the `odd` class something like: `tr.handle.odd { background-color:#f9f9f9 }`.